# Suggestions for NodeJS+MySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules, node-mysql

I'm new here so excuse me if my question is too general or simple. 
Recently, a basic web project was assigned as part of a course, and I'll be using NodeJS+MySQL (and VS Code which seems quite nice), but I have no experience with these 2 at all, so if anyone knows about some tutorial or have any suggestions for me, please let me know. I'm just initiating myself in web development, but as far as I've seen, I really like it. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can choose several node frameworks.I think as a beginner node express framework is the best one.[express.js](https://expressjs.com/)
- For MySQL, you can use an ORM.most of the time I used [sequelizejs](http://sequelizejs.com)
- If you hoping to do some real-time chat thing you can use [socket.io](https://socket.io/)
- You can search node  packages hear [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I  was slightly introduced to express framework before so that was the chosen one, and I already installed MySQL from npm, I'll check sequelize because I've read is one of the favorites!